# Is there any alternative method to filter faces?

Tags: vba, catia

I was trying to filter the faces in the part by using selection & search method

```
Selection.Search ("Topology.Face,sel")
```

Here, Catia takes some time to search and select the faces, so I want to bypass this

is there any alternative method to filter faces without selection ?

Comment: What kind of faces? What do you want to filter?

Comment: I want to filter only Cylindrical Face